# ContactForm 7 doesn't send mail (even if he thinks he did)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a WordPress site that I'm using Contact Form 7 on. I configured it, inserted my template both for mail and form and tried to run it on my web server (online, not local). Problem is - mail doesn't come. I completely don't know where to look for any cause of this issue. I have CF7 installed on two other sites and they are working well. What can it be? Please note, that `mail()` function works well on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the different SMTP plugins available to force Wordpress and Contact Form 7 to use SMTP to send mail rather than mail() and see if you can get email. Some of those plugins have test functions and debug outputs to test both SMTP and mail() so you can figure out what's happening with both. See http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=smtp

Also look in your error logs. Is this your own server? Sounds like a bad path or some sot of php configuration issue. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php to check your php configs.

Comment: Thanks for the SMTP, it works, but with SMTP I always have defualt e-mail as the sender and I need to have the address that my client gave in the form.

Comment: The email needs to be *sent* from the email given in the form? If not, those plugins allow you to change the WP default "from" header.

Comment: When I do recieve an e-mail, it needs to be send from the address written by my client. It works with `mail()`, but not SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

ContactForm7 uses Ajax to call the action where the mail will be sent.
So maybe you get any Javascript error? You can check this with Firebug oder the Chrome Dev Tools.
You also have to include wp_head() and wp_footer() in your template, because the javascript files are queued by Wordpress.
This page may help you: http://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/

Comment: JS is working just fine. It sends mails okay on my localhost, but not on my server.